# Cursor apper odd in Qt application hyperlinks in various widgets

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, qt5

[image: look that black cursor icon it do not follows the system mouse cursor theme]

Any one know how can i fix the icon of cursor ?? 
The app is done in QT and the widget my mouse hovering in the picture is Qlable , actually its not only the problem here cursor appears same in Qwebkit and some other widgets.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-30016 , fixed in Qt 5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cursor shape can be set with `QCursor::setShape()`. It is also possible to set a specific cursor for a specific widget:

`yourWidget.setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);`

and even to override the cursor for your entire application with `QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor()`, e.g.

```
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor));
```

Comment: Using ->>>> QApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor));  changes the cursor of whole application , Thanks it worked .

Comment: is used   ui->label_2->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);  but it still showing black odd cursor . label_2 is Qlabel

Comment: accepted it cause the solution is correct and working in KDE but not in Unity/Gnome . so its a desktop specific bug , and after a bit more digging i found that the issue is caused by cursor theme , cause when i switch KDE mouse cursor theme the odd hand sign over hyper-link is changed by the hyper-link hand of KDE mouse cursor theme .

Comment: The issue is caused by Qt not handling X cursor themes, as explained in the bug report I've linked.